# VBA Bullet listing for individual header items

Tags: vba, ms-word

Attached is my code my I tried to format a bullet list.

For example if I have the following list

I am trying to change to bullet from the following:
[image]

But I managed to change to the following using the code I have describe below,
The is some problem: the 1st bullet point is still bullet form.
The 2nd bullet point should restart the numbering, should be a,a,a,a instead of a,b,c,d
[image]

Attached is my code hope you can assist:

```
Sub ListLevelNumber()
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46119719/determine-bullet-list-style-using-word-vba

'template 1
  With ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
        .NumberFormat = "%1."
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
        .NumberPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0.63)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 0
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = ""
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With

'template 2
With ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(2).ListLevels(1)
        .NumberFormat = "%1)"
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseLetter
        .NumberPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0.63)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 0
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = ""
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With


 With ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(3).ListLevels(1)
        .NumberFormat = ChrW(61607)
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleBullet
        .NumberPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0.63)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 0
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = "Wingdings"
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With


Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph
Dim count As Integer
count = 0
'Select Entire document
'Selection.WholeStory


With Selection
    For Each oPara In .Paragraphs
       
        If oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber = 1 Then
            oPara.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
            ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
            True, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
            wdWord10ListBehavior
        End If
        
        If oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber = 2 Then
            oPara.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
            ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(2), ContinuePreviousList:= _
            False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
            wdWord10ListBehavior
        End If
        
        If oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber = 3 Then
            oPara.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
            ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(3), ContinuePreviousList:= _
            True, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
            wdWord10ListBehavior
        End If
    
                'count = count + 1
        'End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to read up on ListGalleries before you can sdo what you want to do.  Its rather messy.

Comment: "i don't get it working" is not a helpful description of your issue. Please use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72027034/edit) below your question and provide details of exactly what you need help with, e.g. are you getting an error? what does the code do/not do?

Comment: The screenshots in your question indicate that you are trying to create a Multi-level list, but your code creates 3 separate lists.